# WCF Post: Null DataMember Properties

Tags: wcf, post

I am trying to post date to WCF POST method. But the object posted to WCF POST method has no values (null) under any of its property.

Data Contract Class:

```
[DataContract]
public class NewSession
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? date { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string speaker { get; set; }
}
```

WCF Post Method:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/add")]
    public string AddSession(NewSession session)
    {
        //code to add new session
        return "success";
    }
```

jquery code to all WCF Post method:

```
$(".lnk-add").on("click", null, function () {
        var session = [{
            "id": "3",
            "title": "REST 3",
            "date": "05/15/2014",
            "speaker": "Ron Jacobs"
        }];
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Sessions/add',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(session),
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            }
        });
    });
```

In debugger, I get null values (check screenshot attached)
[image]

What can be possible reason(s) of these null values?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you hosting the service?

Comment: I've added the service in an ASP.NET web application and accessing it on an aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem may that you are not indicating that the JSON data contains a NewSession object.

Try this:

```
var session = [{"NewSession":{
  "id": "3",
  "title": "REST 3",
  "date": "05/15/2014",
  "speaker": "Ron Jacobs"
  }}];
```

Comment: I think its not the issue as I am using `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` but not the `Wrapped` or `WrappedRequest`. Still I tried this but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are sending an array of session instead of just a session object.

When I recreate your scenario and use postman to send

```
{"id": "3","title": "REST 3","date": "\/Date(2014-05-15)\/","speaker": "Ron Jacobs"}
```

I get the correct values but not if I send:

```
[{"id": "3","title": "REST 3","date": "\/Date(2014-05-15)\/","speaker": "Ron Jacobs"}]
```

Comment: The problem is the date. If i send `"date": "05/15/2014"` in a session object, it says "400 - Bad request". If I send it in array, values under object are null. If i send date in format you described `"date": "\/Date(2014-05-15)\/"`, I can find the values in session object except date. The value under date is not the one I am sending but its always "1/1/1970 05:00:02 AM". Whats the problem with the date?